# flex/actionscript assignment failing?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, null, flexbuilder

I'm seeing something weird in my actionscript code

I have two classes foo and bar, bar extends foo.  In a model class I have a foo member variable, I assign an bar object to the foo variable.  But after the assignment the foo variable is null.

```
[Bindable] public var f:foo;
public function someFunc(arr:ArrayCollection):void  {  
  if(arr.length > 0) {
    var tempBar:bar = arr.getItemAt(0) as bar;
    if(tempBar != null) {
      tempBar.someProp++;
      f = tempBar;
      // f is now null
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

*EDIT*
Here is the exact code:

```
  [Bindable] public var selectedCustomerJob:IDSCustomer;

  public function selectedJobByIdCallback(evt:Event):void
  {
   var temp:IDSDTOArrayCollection = evt.currentTarget as IDSDTOArrayCollection;
   if(null != temp && temp.length > 0)
   {
    selectedCustomerJob = IDSJob(temp.getItemAt(0));;
    trace("    selectedCustomerJob: " + flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(selectedCustomerJob));
    trace("       jobToSelect type: " + flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(temp.getItemAt(0)));
    trace("jobToSelect super class: " + flash.utils.getQualifiedSuperclassName(temp.getItemAt(0)));
   }
  }
```

this is the trace output:

selectedCustomerJob: null

jobToSelect type: com.intuit.sb.cdm.v2::IDSJob

jobToSelect super class: com.intuit.sb.cdm.v2::IDSCustomer

Answer (score 0):

Casting using the `as` keyword returns `null` when it fails. In this case, the first item in the array collection may not be an object of type `Bar` as you expect; it could be a `Foo` or something else. You can cast subclass object to base-class but not the other way.

Use the parenthesis syntax for casting - it'll throw an exception if cast fails and thus you can figure out the type of `arr.getItemAt(0)`.

```
//Change 
var tempBar:Bar = arr.getItemAt(0) as Bar;

//to 
var tempBar:Bar = Bar(arr.getItemAt(0));
```

to make sure that the first item in the array collection is indeed a `Bar` instance (and not `Foo` or something else).

Otherwise you can find the type using

```
trace(flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(arr.getItemAt(0)));
```

---

```
if(tempBar != null) {
  tempBar.someProp++;
  f = tempBar;
  // f is now null
}
```

By the way, I believe the posted code is not the exact code you ran because for `f` to be `null`, `tempBar` should be `null` as you assigning it to `f`. In that case the code inside `if` should not be executed as you're checking for `null` inside `if`. Even if it enters the `if` block, it will throw a null pointer error (#1009) in the first line where you're trying to increment `tempBar.someProp`